# Defining a universal class in ZFC? Wiki definition question

Tags: set-theory

I'm confused with the concept of a universe in ZFC.  The following two Wiki definitions should be compatible with ZFC.  Does anyone know if they result in the same class of objects?

1. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)#In_ordinary_mathematics) defines a universe as a class of the form $U(X) = \cup_{i=1}^\infty S_i$ where
   $S_0 = X$ and $S_{n+1} = S_n \cup \mathcal P(S_n)$.  For any assignment of $X$ this class $U(X)$ will contain (among other objects) Von Neumann ordinal numbers, ordered tuples and relations.  Wiki then says the universe $U$ can be extended to $U_{\beta}$ so it will cover the n-ary Cartesian Product of $\mathbb N$ by defining $U_{\beta} = \cup_{i=1}^\infty U^{(i)}(X)$ with function composition.
2. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)#In_set_theory) explains how ZFC uses the Von Neumann hierarchy defined as $V_0 := \varnothing, V_{\beta+1} := \mathcal{P} (V_\beta), V_\lambda := \bigcup_{\beta < \lambda} V_\beta$.   It' my understanding that $V_{\epsilon_0}$ forms a proper class containing every countable set in ZFC.

Comment: $V_{\epsilon_0}$ is a set in ZFC, as is $V_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$. It's only $\cup_\alpha V_\alpha$ that's a proper class.

Comment: In (2), I intended for $\lambda = \epsilon_0 = {\omega}^{\omega^{...}}$, maybe the wiki definition is ambiguous with regards to $V$?

Answer (score 4):

First, the use of $\infty$ within a context that works with transfinite ordinals is quite confusing, since it is not clear what is meant with this. Usually, if $\square$ is some operator like $\bigcup$ or $\sum$, a notation such as $\square_{i=0}^\infty$ in mathematics is a way of writing $\square_{i\in \Bbb N}$, which would be the limit of $\square_{i=0}^n$ as the **natural number** $n$ goes to "infinity". However, in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ one often works with infinite quantities, and particularly, you can keep going transfinitely past the natural numbers, and there are many sizes of infinity, so the symbol $\infty$ becomes ambiguous.

---

Let's look at your second definition first. One can define the von Neumann universe as the class of sets $V_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$ as you did:

\begin{align*}
V_0&=\varnothing\\
V_{\alpha+1}&=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)\\
\quad V_{\lambda}&=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}V_\alpha=\bigcup\{V_\alpha\mid \alpha<\lambda\}\quad\text{if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal}
\end{align*}
Then the *universe of all sets* $V$ is defined as the (proper) class of all sets $x$ such that $x\in V_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. You could write this as $V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}}V_\alpha$, where $\mathrm{Ord}$ is the (proper) class of all ordinals, but one should realise that this is not a set.

Now, if $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then $V_\alpha$ is a set. This follows from the axioms of set theory: the empty set is a set, the power set of a set is a set, and the union of a set is a set. One only has to prove that if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, then $\{V_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\lambda\}$ is a set, which uses the axiom of replacement (take the map $\alpha\mapsto V_\alpha$ with domain $\lambda$, then since $\lambda$ is a set, the range of this map is a set).

Under the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, one can prove that **every set** is contained in $V$, using the axiom of regularity.

Now, the ordinal $\epsilon_0$ is itself a limit ordinal. You can prove this with the axiom of replacement: consider the map $\omega\to\mathrm{Ord}$ given by $n\mapsto \omega^{\omega^{\dots^{\omega}}}$ where the stack of $\omega$'s has length $n$, then the range of this map is a set of ordinals, whose union is a stack $\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\dots}}}$ of length $\omega$, i.e. the ordinal $\epsilon_0$. Since $\epsilon_0$ is an ordinal, and thus a set, it is also the case that $V_{\epsilon_0}$ is a set. It does not contain every countable set either, since $\epsilon_0\notin V_{\epsilon_0}$ and $\epsilon_0$ is countable. In fact, no $V_\alpha$ contains all countable sets, since $\{\alpha\}\notin V_\alpha$ and the set $\{\alpha\}$ is countable (finite even).

---

So what is the first definition about? This is about how many sets we *usually* need to do "ordinary mathematics" with. If we have a space $X$, we often use objects such as functions on $X$, or topologies on $X$, or maybe the set  $X^X$ of all functions from $X$ to itself, and so on.

All of these concepts can be modelled as sets, and they live somewhere in the hierarchy of $V_\alpha$'s, but the main point is that we do not need the entire universe $V$ to do most of our mathematics in. For example:

- a topology on $X$ is a set of subsets, thus every topology lives in $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$,
- a pair of elements in $X$ lies in $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$, so a function (which is a set of pairs) lies in $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X)))$,
- the set of all functions then lies in $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))))$.

Hence, for our "everyday" needs in mathematics, it is usually sufficient to only consider the sets in $U(X)$. It is easy to see that $V_\omega\subset U(X)$, since $V_\omega=U(\varnothing)$, so $U(X)$ contains all [hereditarily finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set), which includes the finite ordinals (natural numbers). It does not necessarily contain transfinite ordinals, but one rarely needs these in the majority of mathematics.

Since the spaces $X$ that are considered in most fields of mathematics are quite "simple" as well, most of the spaces that are regularly considered are already present in $V_{\omega+\omega}=U(V_\omega)$. For example, all (hereditarily) finite sets can be found in $V_\omega$, the set of natural numbers can be found in $V_{\omega+1}$, the set of all real numbers in $V_{\omega+2}$, and so on.

Comment: When you say in ZFC every set in contained in $V$, do you mean $V_{{\omega}+{\omega}}$ as $V_{\lambda}$?  Does this $V$ include the infinite cartesian product of $\mathbb N$? You say $V_\omega = U(\{\})$, but I look at the definitions and one has a union and the other not.  Maybe the result is the same?  How is $V_{{\omega}+{\omega}} = U(V_\omega)$?

Comment: @Nick I mean $V$ being the union of $V_\alpha$ for **every ordinal** $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then $V_\alpha$ is a set itself, and $\alpha\notin V_\alpha$, so $V$ is not equal to $V_\lambda$ for any ordinal $\lambda$, since it does not contain every set. As for $V_\omega=U(\varnothing)$, we have $V_\omega=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}V_n$ and $U(\varnothing)=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}U^{(n)}(\varnothing)$. Furthermore, $V_n=U^{(i)}(\varnothing)$ is easy to prove. Showing that $V_{\omega+\omega}=U(V_\omega)$ is similarly done, by noting that $V_\alpha\cup\mathcal P(V_\alpha)=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)$.

Comment: I get the impression that you're relatively unfamiliar with ordinals themselves, nor with transfinite induction. It's hard to understand these concepts properly without knowing the basics, so perhaps it makes sense to get familiar with those first. Proving basic statements from [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) are excellent practice material.

Comment: You define V "where Ord is the (proper) class of all ordinals".  How is this class defined?  I considered $\omega = Ord$, but it is a set.

Comment: @Nick I strongly recommend you read up on what ordinals are and how transfinite induction & transfinite recursion work. The class of ordinals is defined exactly as it is called: as the class of all ordinals... If that doesn't make sense, you're not going to understand what $V$ or $V_\alpha$ is either, because then you don't seem to understand what an ordinal is. You can't "use" $\omega=\mathrm{Ord}$, because $\mathrm{Ord}$ and $\omega$ are not just variable you can choose, they have fixed definitions.

Comment: So the *Ord* is not defined by the axiom of infinity (VN ordinals) where $I$ is a class $\exists \mathbf{I} \, ( \emptyset \in \mathbf{I} \, \land \, \forall x \in \mathbf{I} \, ( \, ( x \cup \{x\} ) \in \mathbf{I} ) )$?  I realize *Ord* is a class to avoid a paradox.  In regards to $\omega$, it was my understanding it contained all the ordinals, but I suspect as $\omega \not \in \omega$ causes a problem for $\omega$ being *Ord*.

Comment: @Nick, you're not making any sense. $\mathrm{Ord}$ is defined by being the class of all ordinals. That's the definition. Ordinals are transitive sets whose elements are well-ordered by $\in$. Ord is a class, because if it were a set, then it would be a transitive set well-ordered by $\in$, and thus by definition it would not be complete (since it wouldn't contain itself: no well-ordered set can contain itself by definition of well-order). $\omega$ is the smallest infinite ordinal (smallness being with respect to $\in$), also known as the order-type of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: $\omega$ is just some ordinal, it's not a variable, you can't state it "being Ord" because it's not Ord... The axiom of infinity allows infinite sets to exist, and implies that $\omega$ is a set, but it's by no means the set of all ordinals: $\omega$ itself is an ordinal not contained in $\omega$, as are any other infinite ordinal.

Comment: I believe that the comment section of stackexchange is not the right place for you to learn more about ordinals. I'll once again repeat my recommendation to properly learn about ordinals (from a book, such as Hrbacek & Jech's *Introduction to Set Theory*, or Kunen's *Foundations of Mathematics*, or Jech's *Set Theory*) before continuing with the von Neumann hierarchy. I'll leave this conversation here.

Comment: Regarding $\omega$ I agree with you and it is due to the  Burali-Forti paradox and $Ord$ defined as a class to solve it.  My original question was if $V_\beta = U(X)$, which you answered although I'm still confused how $U(\emptyset) = \cup_{n\in\omega} U^{(n)}(\emptyset)$ even with $V_\beta \cup \mathcal P(V_\beta) = \mathcal P(V_\beta)$.  Appreciate any more guidance there

Comment: @Vsotvep: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4418232). Not making any sense indeed!