# Solving an equation for a specific variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve for $v_1$, but am having difficulty.  Does anyone know the steps I'm missing?

$$v_1 (1 + \frac {m_1}{m_2}) = - u_1 + \frac {m_1}{m_2}u_1 + 2 u_2$$

The solution is:

$$v_1 = \frac {m_1 - m_2}{m_1 + m_2} u_1 + \frac {2 m_2}{m_1 + m_2} u_2$$

Dividing by $(1 + \frac {m_1}{m_2})$ I think is the first step, but unsure what steps to take from there.

Comment: You can factor $u_1$ in the RHS. Also put everything on the same denominator (i.e $1+\frac{m_1}{m_2}$ is$\frac{m_1+m_2}{m_2}$ ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do first is multiply both sides by $m_2$. This gets us

$$v_1(m_2+m_1)=-u_1m_2+m_1u_1+2u_2m_2$$

Now we can distribute out a $u_1$.

$$v_1(m_2+m_1)=u_1(m_1-m_2)+2u_2m_2$$

Now, simply divide by $m_2+m_1$.

$$v_1=\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}u_1+\frac{2m_2}{m_1+m_2}u_2$$